# negative margin top in NavigationView layout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, navigationview

I have custom DrawerLayout with below codes.
I don't know why my layout (drawer_layout) take margin from top and the red close button that you can see below is being covered.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
tools:context=".DashboardActivity"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:openDrawer="start">

[Some other elements here ...]


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginRight="-64dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<include layout="@layout/drawer_layout" />

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

and its my custom layout for NavigationView :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/primary_color"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
     [Properties]
 />

<TextView

    [Properties]
    />

<TextView

    [Properties]
    />

<ImageView
     [Properties]
 />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/drawer_close_image_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/radius_background_acent_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

but in result I have a negative margin top that can be seen in below picture.

[image: Margin from top]

How can I remove that margin from top and show my NavigationView layout correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`. That line tells the layout engine to place elements using the whole screen, including the bit under the status bar.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` is causing your problem.

Try removing this line